HPE MSA 2060 FC volume mount on multiple Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS servers

HPE MSA 2060 FC SAN volume created and assigned to multiple hosts (Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS).

The following commands used to mount the volume:


sudo rescan-scsi-bus.sh
sudo multipath -ll
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/mpathX
sudo mkdir -p /san/
sudo chmod +777 /san
sudo mount /dev/mapper/mpathX /san


mkfs command only applied on first host.

3rd party applications start writing files under /san/ and all folders and files found and accessible without issues on the host where the application is running.

The other host fails to get all folders and files under /san/ unless I do umount and mount to get it refreshed or use `e2fsck! So how to fix this problem? How to make the SAN volume data seen by multiple hosts just like what happens with normal shared folders using NFS or SMB?



You have to use a clustered filesystem, and your setup necessitates the use of a shared disk filesystem flavour specifically.
Quite strange: you use mkfs.xfs which creates an XFS, but then you say something about e2fsck which is designed for ext2/3/4, and could not work with XFS, which provides its own repair tool, fsck.xfs. Anyway, both XFS and ext4 are not suitable for such a setup. These filesystems can only be mounted on one host at a time; they must be unmounted on one host, block-level caches flushed, and only then it is allowed to mount it on another host.
Out of the list OCFS2 and GFS2 are the proper clustered shared disk filesystems typically available in any Linux distro.
The actual performance of the filesystem will depend on the networking (not just SAN), because it uses a distributed locking which is affected by network delays between hosts.

Regarding e2fsck initially I used mkfs.ext4 then changed it to xfs, because MSA docs states that ext4 not supported while xfs is.

Regarding clustered filesystems, It seems to me a complex addition! Fiber Channel SAN allows multiple hosts to share one volume, but they don't say what kind of software can make use of that. almost all software's writing data files not data blocks! on earlier deployment we used NFS and it worked well.

ext4 and XFS are supported up to the exactly same extent, as any other filesystem out there. It's not MSA to bother what kind of filesystem (or other structure) I'm going to use on top of it's provided block device

If it's still not clear from the answer: yes, that's complex solution, but it's the only way to safely mount the same block device on multiple hosts simultaneously. The solution is reasonably complex because the problem itself is actually quite hard. You want to have coherent filesystem caches, coordinated metadata and data updates, etc., that's what makes CFS different from ordinary local filesystem (which will be destroyed if you mount it simultaneously). // NFS is kind of NAS solution, while FC is SAN; these things work on different levels of abstraction, and aren't directly comparable.

The Ubuntu docs have fairly good coverage of the various HA topics.  https://documentation.ubuntu.com/server/explanation/intro-to/high-availability/
